# Google Maps initMap add parameters to function

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a basic HTML website, that has a few Google Maps in it. Each sub-site has its own map.
Each site has this code, that calls the JS function:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript("../assets/dist/js/listing-details-map.js", function(){});
  </script>
```

And this is the JS function:

```
      initMap = (function(){
      var myLatLng = {lat: 47.6205588, lng: -122.3212725};

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatLng,
        scrollwheel: false,
      });
      var icon = 'assets/dist/img/company/map-marker.png'
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: 'Hello World!'
      });
    }());
```

I would like to pass the parameters for lat and lng in the script in the original file, so that i would not need to make a copy of that file. 
How can that be done? 
I have tried the ordinary way, by just inputting parameters inside of the function call, but that resulted in errors....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was an easy fix :) Just make global variables and call them in the JS file, and it works!